# slideshow using a servlet

Tags: java, javascript, image, servlets, slideshow

I am trying a slideshow using a servlet . Though the photos are loaded but is not a slideshow. What i get is a series of images.

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;

public class PhotoCollection extends HttpServlet{

private String array[] = {"first.jpg","second.jpg","third.jpg","fourth.jpg"};

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException,ServletException {
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
            writer.println("<html>");
            writer.println("<head>");
                writer.println("<title>");
                writer.println("SlideShow");
                writer.println("</title>");
            writer.println("</head>");
            writer.println("<body>");
            writer.println("<table>");
            writer.println("<tr>");
            try {
                for(int i=0;i<=3;i++) {
                    writer.println("<td>");
                    writer.println("<img src=" + array[i] + " height=100 width=110>");
                    writer.println("</td>");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            }catch(Exception exc) {
                writer.println("<br />" + exc + "<br />");
            }
            writer.println("</tr>");
            writer.println("</table>");
            writer.println("</body>");
            writer.println("</html>");
}
```

}

I have made the thread sleep 1 second but that doesn't affect the loading. How can i do a slideshow using it ? What changes do i have to make in the above servlet ?

Comment: You're making a major conceptual mistake here. Server side web languages like Servlets (and JSP) runs on webserver and produces client side web languages like HTML/CSS/JS. The webserver sends this HTML/CSS/JS to webbrowser upon a HTTP request. Once the webbrowser has retrieved it all, it will run the retrieved HTML/CSS/JS. You need to perform the slideshow in the client side, not in the server side. Don't do `Thread.sleep()` in a servlet! I'd suggest to learn basic web development concepts before continuing.

Comment: @ BalusC Thank you. That was major conceptual mistake

Comment: Slideshows would typically be done using JS.  I don't know if the HTML 5 canvas has also been used in more recent times to assist in that.  Added JavaScript tag.

Answer (score 1):

You should use jQuery plugins for displaying it on browser pretty, use servlet just to serve image

**Note** : adding sleep in doGet doesn't make sense here, out put is sent once the method is executed so it would pause the execution

Comment: that may be true. but is there a way out in java ?

Comment: if you don't have image processing (reading from DB/adding effect), from the code it seems you are just rendering the plain static images then why you need java to involved? just jQuery plugin wuild do it